# How to see which MySQL queries that are stored in query cache?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, query-cache

After many lectures, I couldn't find a way to see **which MySQL queries are stored into
query cache** ; In phpMyAdmin you can see how many queries is in with **Qcache_inserts** 
but how do I see  **the query details** .
If you know any tool or any way, I'm very interested.
The goal is to improve my script and see clearly which queries are put in query cache or not.

Thanks to all,
regards,
jessica

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can ask the query cache to just dump the queries that it is caching. You can, however, try a query and see if it was cached. If you have a query that you suspect is not being cached, run it a few times and see if it was served from the cache. The details of how to see that are available at: http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/04/03/was-a-query-served-from-mysql-query-cache/

Answer (score -1):

,
i answer me with good news for you,
its possible to see the content of query cache with maria db !!
definitly this fork is much better than mysql , totaly compatible !
mariadb has release this awesome plugin : query cach info , see here :
https://kb.askmonty.org/en/query_cache_info-plugin/

Cheers !

Jessica